# How to minimize the SQL in my case?

Tags: sql, oracle

So this is my SQL -

```
select t.form_id, 
       t.created, 
       ui.first_name || ui.last_name as "created by name", 
       t.updated, 
       ui2.first_name || ui2.last_name as "updated by name"
from module_transport t
join user_info ui on ui.id = t.entered_by 
join user_info ui2 on ui2.id = t.last_updated_by
join client c on c.id = t.individual_id and lower(c.first_name) = 'gvznsbuv' and lower(c.last_name) = 'elpveol'
join company_info p on p.id = t.prov_id and p.code = 'AGB-02'
where to_char(t.created, 'MON-YYYY') = 'MAR-2014'
union all
select f.form_id, 
       f.created, 
       ui.first_name || ui.last_name as "created by name", 
       f.updated, 
       ui2.first_name || ui2.last_name as "updated by name"
from module_food f
join user_info ui on ui.id = f.created_by 
join user_info ui2 on ui2.id = f.last_updated_by
join client c on c.id = f.client and lower(c.first_name) = 'gvznsbuv' and lower(c.last_name) = 'elpveol'
join company_info p on p.id = f.prov_id and p.code = 'AGB-02'
where to_char(f.created, 'MON-YYYY') = 'MAR-2014';
```

Here, both parts joined by the 'union all' clause have the same logic. Is there any way to write the logic in one place which will apply both of the parts? 
Also, how efficient would that be?

Comment: why did you select sql-server tag?

Comment: Because this SQL should be familiar to both Oracle and MSSQL users. So, the question might get answered by any of the platform users.

Comment: Yes it might be, but you might also get an answer that doesn't work in oracle at all -- and with that, waste the time of people answering to the question

Comment: @SamiulAlHossaini: that's what the "sql" tag is for.

Comment: Ok the tag is removed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **'WITH'** clause in Oracle to simplify the query. In your query example the Company_Info table and the Client table can be subqueried usingthe With clause with an alias name and refer the alias in your join statement.

Refer to this [link](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) for more info on WITH clause.

Example SQL with 'WITH' clause

```
  WITH dept_count AS (
    SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
    FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
  SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
     dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
  FROM   emp e,
     dept_count dc
  WHERE  e.deptno = dc.deptno;
```

Using this way can simplify your logic and can also fasten your query performance.